# Chrome Extension Screenshot upload 503 error

Tags: file-upload, google-chrome-extension, http-status-code-503

I am trying to upload my chrome extension to the Chrome Web Store. Everything is ok, except for images. None of my images upload, they get stuck on processing. My store icon image uploaded fine, but the screenshots and tiles do not. I get this error in console:

[image: 503 Error from console]

I have tried this many times, over a course of months. I have tried clearing cookies and site data, and with incognito on and off. I have asked this on the chrome web store help but I did what they said and then my question was locked. Does anyone know how to fix this/Find someone who can??

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, I figured it out, the images needed to be exactly 1280x800  in size. After resizing my images, the 503 disapeared. I used the following ffmpeg command to resize:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/original-image.png -vf scale=1280:800 ~/output-image.png
```